# To and From return the same email id in php

Tags: php, html, email, pear

This is my php code:

```
<?php
        require_once "Mail.php";

        $name=trim($_POST['name']);
        $email=trim($_POST['email']);
        $phone=trim($_POST['phone']);
        $message=trim($_POST['message']);

                $from = $email;
                $to = "fyproject.com@gmail.com";    //$_SESSION['mto'];//
                $subject = "You have a message from '$name'";
                $body = $message;

                $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; //"smtp.gmail.com";
                $port = "465";//"587";
                $username = "fyproject.com@gmail.com";
                $password = "************";
                $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                      'To' => $to,
                      'Subject' => $subject);

                $smtp =@ Mail::factory('smtp',
                      array ('host' => $host,
                        'port' => $port,
                        'auth' => true,
                        'username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password));

                $mail = @$smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
                    echo "Trying to send email ....";

                if (@PEAR::isError($mail)) {
                      echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
                } else {
                      echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
                }
    ?>
```

My HTML form is something like this:

```
<form action="includes/contact.php" method="post" id="ContactForm">     
                                        <fieldset class="left"> 
                                                    <div class="block">
                                                    <label class="name padRight3">
                                                        <span class="title1">Name:</span>
                                                        <span class="bg"><input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,20}\s[A-Za-z]{3,20}$" title="Type your name and surname. Special Characters not allowed" class="input" required autofocus></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                     <label class="email">
                                                        <span class="title1">Email:</span>
                                                        <span class="bg"><input type="email" name="email" class="input" required></span>
                                                        </label>   

                                                     <label class="phone">
                                                     <span class="title1">Phone:</span>
                                                        <span class="bg"><input type="tel" name="phone" pattern="\d{10}" class="input"></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                     </div>

                                                     <div class="block">
                                                     <label class="message">
                                                     <span class="title1">Message:</span>
                                                        <span class="bg"><textarea rows="1" cols="2" name="message" required></textarea></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                     </div>
                                                     <div class="formButtons">
                                                      <div class="formBtn">
                                                            <input type="submit" value="send" />
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class="formBtn">
                                                            <input type="reset" value="clear" />
                                                      </div>
                                                     </div> 
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
```

I created this code for the contact me page. Now when user submits the contact form which has the fields name, email, tel and message, i recieve the email where from and to are both my email id. Though i ve provided the attribute name='email' and method='post' in the form. Its not retrieving the users email, rather its displaying my email which I've provided for receiving the mail. But rest of the field are working fine. I don't understand where i am going wrong. Any help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Inputs with type="email" aren't sent in old versions of IE. Could be that, otherwise everything looks fine. Please include your form HTML.

Comment: I'm using chrome.. Okay i'll add my form

Comment: please change also tel type ...

Comment: @Neeraj why?? Whats wrong with that? Its working fine.. Only email is giving me a problem